# Automatic Hard Drive Access

Tags: hard-drive, bittorrent

I run QBittorrent for torrenting on Ubuntu, and I have it set to drop downloads in the same hard drive, but on a different partition from what the OS runs on. Before I'm able to start downloading, I have to manually navigate to the file path of the hard drive, as if the system has no access to it until I manually go and visit it.

While I CAN manually access the hard drive prior to opening the program, it's extremely annoying to get 20 errors flashing when I forget to.

Is there a way to over ride this other than installing to a different location? I have my partitions setup in a way that it would be difficult to do it any other way (windows is on my other internal).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your partition to the `/etc/fstab` file so that it's automatically mounted. Extensive documentation is available on the net on how to add a partition to fstab so you should be able to do it easily.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I think automouting the disk partition at boot time can solve your issue. You will need to edit /etc/fstab file and enable automount for the specific drive there. There is a good tutorial for automounting here http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html.

Answer (score 1):

You must mount permanently the partition.

Here in [Ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/) we have a very good documentation and a wiki page.

First read [Introduction to Fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) so you can understand better what you will do 
and then 
read [automatically mount partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) to see how you can mount permanently your partition.

Thanks